# node js Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined using regexp

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeerror

router.js code :

---

```
var file = __dirname + '\\text\\article.txt';

fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function(err, data) {

    var regexp1 = /\{title:(.*)\}/ig;
    var matches1 = regexp1.exec(data);
    data = data.replace(regexp1, '');

    var regexp2 = /\[img:([0-9]{1,4})\]/ig;
    var matches2;
    while ((matches2 = regexp2.exec(data)) != null) {
        data = data.replace(matches2[0], '<img src=\"../../imgs/' + matches2[1] + '.png\" /\>');
    }

    var regexp3 = /(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g;
    data = data.replace(regexp3, '<br />');

    respond.render('view.pug', {
        title: matches1[1],
        article: data
    });
});
```

---

(why code boxes are automatically broken? / i use line to distinguish.)

if i access on website, console has following error:

---

```
C:\Dev\whitenoise\testsite\router.js:29
data = data.replace(regexp1, '');
           ^
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\Dev\whitenoise\testsite\router.js:29:16)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:366:13)

---

what is this?? i cannot find solution in google, pls help

Comment: Check by console logging data would be undefined.

Comment: There's possibly an error `function(err, data)` which you are not checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *data* variable is undefined, which means there could have been some error while reading the file, most probably related to its path. Add

```
var file = __dirname + '\\text\\article.txt';
console.log(file);
```

And check if the result will lead to your file. Also, since you're reading a file on the server, you should be using url, and not paths. So it should probably be something like

```
var file = __dirname + '/text/article.txt';
```

with '/' instead of '\\'